# How to apply same page without changing distance between lines

Tags: samepage

I am trying to make sure the items in my list remain in the same page so I put them in a samepage environnment, but the line distance of the previous page automatically changed to fit the change that go with the samepage environment. Is there a way to keep the distance between lines of previous page the same?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! As no one, on this site, has a crystal ball, it's impossible to help. Please post a minimal, yet *complete* code illustrating the problem.

Comment: In 1994 Leslie Lamport said that "The `\samepage` command still works, but is now of little use."

Comment: Then is there any command with the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

It would have been really helpful if you had provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that showed your problem. As it is I have no idea what you have done so I had to waste time coming up with something that might be like your code.

Try using a `minipage` environment that will not break across pages.

```
% samepageprob.tex  SE 565746

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]


\begin{samepage}
%\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
%\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\item First
\item Second
\item Third
%\end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
%\end{minipage}
\end{samepage}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The above MWE is an attempt at what your code might look like. Try (un)commenting the several environments to see what their effects are.

In any case my use of the `samepage` hs no effect on the surrounding text.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try to improve my question style next time